# Moving Google Drive to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

I'd like to move my cloud data from Google Drive (the old G Suite) to OneDrive. I have the problem that the internal migration tool aka Mover is not working very well, because, I presume, there's just too much data to move (20TB). So I'm wondering what other approaches I could take to move cloud data.

- There are cloud-to-cloud services, e.g. MultCloud or CloudHQ, but these are very expensive for such a lot of data. With CloudHQ, their definition of "1 user" is bound to the email address. OneDrive Business generates a new email on registration, so you're already two users by their terms.
- There's `rclone`, obviously, but it would take a lot of time. I read some people get a windows VPS server for this task, but I don't know how that is done.
- I'm also interested in any other ideas and approaches that won't take a lifetime to finish.

Thank you.

Comment: Whichever way you try, it will take a lifetime to complete. This is because, Both the google servers and the onedrive servers will limit the speed of transfer. so the best way you probaby have is rclone only

Comment: @saaranshgarg but then the question remains how I'd actually do that on a VPS, because most limit traffic. What services are out there? Someone recommended Packet. They don't exist anymore.

Comment: You can take help from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/seedboxes/comments/5om3om/vps_for_transfering_30tb_files_from_gdrive_to_acd/) reddit thread

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/seedboxes/comments/5om3om/vps_for_transfering_30tb_files_from_gdrive_to_acd/dckhg16?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) relpy is the most useful

Comment: This question seems familiar like it was deleted after being closed familiar